# Android vs. NGDC Magnetic Declination API Discrepancies

Tags: android, gps

I have an Android project that uses the Android API to calculate the declination at a specific location. I have a non-Android project that calls into the National Geophysical Data Center's API to calculate the declination at a specific location. Both APIs are based on the same 2015-2020 World Magnetic Model, yet both APIs produce different declinations (the variance of which I've noticed to be up to a degree in certain locations). I need the output in both projects to be similar, but I also need accuracy. So I'm wondering:

1) with the same latitude, longitude, altitude and date as inputs, is there any other factor that could account for the aforementioned variance other than the API's themselves? (again, both are using the same WMM)

2) would it be safe to assume that the NGDC API is probably more accurate than the Android API? I'm making this assumption only because this is the particular area of expertise of the NGDC.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the Android API, but I am familiar with the WMM and the NGDC software:

1. The output declination should be similar (to within 1 degree), regardless of software used, for the same position in space and time. There are many variations of algorithm and coordinate conversions that can introduce discrepancies, but these should be less than 1 degree at Earth's surface. You may see greater variation in values particularly at high altitudes and at high geographic and/or magnetic latitudes due to the particular algorithms used.
2. The NGDC software *should* be definitive, any other versions are derived from these. Perhaps compare the values from the Android [NGDC software](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml) to their [web calculators](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/calculators.shtml) or C software to check any variation their software gives relative to what you've seen?